# Issue with PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I need to pass a PFObject to 2 views, first one is detail and second is a segue from the detail. I can easily pass the PFObject to the detail, using `PFObject *obj = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, `detailVC.object = object` in prepareForSegue to a property of the detail view controller, but when I try to pass from the detail to the third view, using `vc.object = self.object` in prepareForSegue then the value of the PFObject in third view is nil. What is the problem?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]) { 
         thirdVC *vc = (thirdVC *)segue.destinationViewController; 
         vc.object = self.object; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Please show your code for invoking the third view.

Comment: @Paulw11 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {
        thirdVC *vc = (thirdVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
        
        vc.object = self.object;
    }
}

Comment: And which method are you trying to access the object in in the third VC?  Have you set a breakpoint in the `prepareForSegue` code to confirm that `self.object` isn't null?

Comment: Double check that the name of the segue is correct and that you actually set up the identifier in Storyboard.

Comment: @Paulw11 in the second view the object is ok. However I check to see in the third view's viewDidLoad if the PFObject is nil and it indeed is...

Comment: @DBoyer Yes it is all set up correctly

Comment: Check it in `viewWillAppear`.  I suspect that `viewDidLoad` is too early

Answer (score 0):

I often found this error when I tried to segue to a VC embedded within its own navigation controller. Make sure it is not, and if it is use this to refer to the controller instead

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"<#Segue Name#>"]) {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        <#UIViewController#> *controller = (<#UIViewController#> *)nav.topViewController;
        controller.object = self.object;
    }
```

Other than that, I can only think to log the object inside the second VC's prepareForSegue and see if it exists there